# How to autocapitalize an inspector text field in jointJS/Rappid

Tags: jquery, uppercase, jointjs, capitalize, rappid

In jointJS I want when editing in an inspector text field to autocapitalize it.

Do I have to alter inspector.js code or to create a new var in my main.js code to do it?

In jointJS documentation there is no reference for capitalize feature.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem this way(Inside the code I initialize my Inspector) using:

```
cell.on('change: inspectorfieldname', function(cell, change, opt) {
var test = cell.get('inspectorfieldname');
var upper= test.toUpperCase();
cell.set('inspectorfieldname', upper);              

        })
```